# How to define nested hash_map in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, hashmap, nested

I have a problem about `hash_map` (or `unordered_map`). In MSVS2008, I can define a nested `hash_map` like:

```
hash_map<int, hash_map<int, float>> nestedHashMap
```

(Omitting corresponding namespace.)

My question is how to define `nestedHashMap` in Linux, because if I define the same way, there is a compiling error.

Comment: The syntax *should* be the same. Can you show us the error you get?

Comment: If you show the exact error message from the compiler, it will be very useful. We can only guess that you were compiling in C++98/C++03 mode (default for g++ so far) and forgot that ">>" to double-close-angle-bracket is allowed only in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

C++03 needs a space between two `>` symbols, you need to write your code like:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, double> >
```

C++11 fixed this "bug".

I guess you missed `-std=c++11` when compiling your program.

Recent versions of Visual C++ automatically enables C++11 feature without any command line options required, but GCC and Clang need `-std=c++11` to enable C++11 features.